# No such column, SQLite GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

Following is the struct of the Genre Model :

```
type Genre struct {
    ImageId   int
    GenreType string
}
```

I am executing the following query for finding all the genreTypes for an ImageId. The code is as follows:

```
func getGenresOfImage(DB *gorm.DB, w http.ResponseWriter, imageId int) ([]string, error) {
    var genres []string
    var allGenres []models.Genre
    genresOfCurrentImage := DB.Where("ImageId = ?", strconv.Itoa(imageId)).Find(&allGenres)
    genreRows, err := genresOfCurrentImage.Rows()
    if err != nil {
        SendErrorResponse(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        // error is returned here
        return genres, err
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Images.go:46 no such column: ImageId
[0.908ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM `genres` WHERE ImageId = "1"
```

Is the syntax that I am using wrong for finding the all the genres associated with an imageId? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your column name will be `image_id`.

As the gorm documentation says:

> Column db name uses the field’s name’s snake_case by convention.

The tables get generated this way when you use gorm's auto migrate feature.

For further info see: https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#Column-Name

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the default naming strategy [here](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#NamingStrategy), you can see that the `image_id` column name is expected in the query (assuming that `image_id` is the name of your column in the database).

with this in mind, there are few options you can try out:

Use `image_id` in the `Where` method:

```
DB.Where("image_id = ?", strconv.Itoa(imageId)).Find(&allGenres)
```

Use struct to pass the condition to the `Where` method:

```
DB.Where(&models.Genre{ ImageID: imageId}).Find(&allGenres)
```

Or, if your column in the database is actually named `ImageId`, you can add this to the `models.Genre` struct:

```
type Genre struct {
 // other fields
 ImageID int `gorm:"column:ImageId"`
}
```

Comment: Both the answers are correct, however, I can only mark one as the correct one, hence I marked the one answered earlier. Thank you so much!